# Bennett atmospheric equation

Tags: python, physics

How do you implement the Bennett atmospheric equation in Python?

The equation is:

[image]

where `h` is the true altitude in degrees, refraction `R` in arc minutes

Comment: You should specify what you exactly want. Do you want to get `h` when you have `R` ?

Comment: get R when I have h

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: Are you basically asking what the `cot` function is?  It's pretty hard to discern what you're finding difficult here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look to the [mathematical functions in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html).

If `cot` is the cotangent, this very simple script will do the work:

```
import math
def R(h):
  return 1.02 / math.tan( h + 10.3 / (h + 5.11) )
print R(1)
```